# Count number of elements in TypedArray in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below is modified version of a code taken from the book *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*.

```js
// First argument is the type of array that should be returned
// Remaining arguments are all the typed arrays that should be concatenated

function numElements(typedArrayConstructor, ...typedArrays) {
    // Count the total elements in all arrays
    return typedArrays.reduce((x,y) => (x.length || x) + y.length);
}

console.log(numElements(Int32Array, Int8Array.of(1, 2, 3), Int16Array.of(4, 5, 6), Float32Array.of(7, 8, 9)));
```

My question is what does the `(x.length || x)` do? Why do we need to perform an `or` operation on `x.length` and `x`?

Comment: The real mystery to me is what the point of that "constructor" argument is, because the function always return a number.

Comment: the `||` in javascript has semantics of boolean "OR", but the language is designed such as it can be also used for "default value". If `x.length` evaluate to something "falsy" (notably  `0` or `undefined`), then the expression `x.length || x` will evaluate to `x` (the right part). It could be surpsing, that the result of an `||` operation is not (necessarily) a boolean in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `.reduce()` is invoked with only one argument, the very first iteration uses element 0 as the first callback parameter and element 1 as the second.

In your case, that means that on the first iteration, `x` will be one of the arrays (note that `y` is *always* an array).  Thus that little expression differentiates between when it's the first iteration and when it's a subsequent iteration by taking advantage of the fact that

```
someNumber.length
```

is always `undefined`. (As correctly noted in another answer, it's critical to recall that `(undefined || x)` will always be `x`, whatever its value may be.) On subsequent iterations therefore `x` is the running total of the array lengths.

The `.reduce()` could have been written as follows instead:

```
return typedArrays.reduce((x,y) => x + y.length, 0);
```

By passing the second argument (0) to `.reduce()`, the first callback invocation will be the same as the others, and `x` will always be a number.

Answer (score 2):

A little more explanation to go with Pointy's answer:

The `||` in JavaScript isn't just a logical OR operation, it deals with "truthy/falsey" values, not just booleans.

`undefined` is falsey. When the first operand of `||` is falsey, the second operand is evaluated, and becomes the result of the expression. Thus `undefined || 0` equals 0.

In your sample code, this means when `x` is 0, you add 0, and get a proper numeric result. If you try to add to `undefined` to another number, all of your calculations turn into `NaN` after that.

Comment: So, `x.length` will be used only for the first iteration, and for the subsequent iterations, `x` will be an integer storing current total length whose `length` property will be `undefined`. Am I correct? @Pointy 's rewritten method makes much more sense and is more understandable.

Comment: Yes that is the case, provided in my response

Comment: It's definitely clearer and more efficient to explicitly use the starting value of 0, like in Pointy's updated answer, rather than mess with `(x.length || x)`. I just wanted to add a little more explanation about how and why your original code works. Once you know how `||` and `&&` actually work, realizing that they do more than a simple logical OR, a bunch of little JavaScript tricks are unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

If x has any elements and x exists then use the length in the sum. Otherwise if length is undefined then return the current element x

**Example 1:**  - happens on first iteration of reduce loop

x is array [1, 2, 3]

```
     x.length || x -> returns the length of array or current total 

     // summation of code would do the following 
     firsthArrayLength  + secondArrayLength = newTotal
```

**Example 2:** - happens on rest of iterations of reduce loop

x is integer 5

```
    x.length || x -> returns x since length of integer is undefined

    // summation of code would do the following 
    currentTotal + curLength = newTotal
```

NOTE: Keep in mind that with this example if any of the arrays is null or undefined then it will throw since we cannot access property length of undefined or null

Answer (score 0):

So sad that is taken from a book. Using `reduce` and `||` like that is reckless and *unprofessional* -

```js
// First argument is the type of array that should be returned
// Remaining arguments are all the typed arrays that should be concatenated
const numElements = (constructor, ...arrs) =>
  new constructor(arrs.reduce((r, a) => r + a.length, 0))

const result =
  numElements
    ( Int32Array
    , Int8Array.of(1, 2, 3)
    , Int16Array.of(4, 5, 6)
    , Float32Array.of(7, 8, 9)
    )
    
console.log(result.constructor)
console.log(result)

// Int32Array
// { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

The description of the function says it should concat the other arrays, not just initialise an empty typed array. Here's what that might look like -

```js
// First argument is the type of array that should be returned
// Remaining arguments are all the typed arrays that should be concatenated
const concatMixed = (constructor, ...arrs) =>
{ const r = new constructor(arrs.reduce((r, a) => r + a.length, 0))
  let i = 0
  for (const a of arrs)
    for (const val of a)
      r[i++] = val
  return r
}

const result =
  concatMixed
    ( Int32Array
    , Int8Array.of(1, 2, 3)
    , Int16Array.of(4, 5, 6)
    , Float32Array.of(7.1, 8.2, 9.3)
    )
    
console.log(result.constructor)
console.log(result)

// Int32Array
// { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```